# "User config directory is not writeable" while training yolov5

Tags: python, yolov5

[image]Whenever I try training using my custom dataset I get this message constantly:

```
WARNING ⚠️ user config directory is not writeable, defaulting to '\tmp\Ultralytics'.
```

Moreover during training each epoch's `"_loss"` value is nan which results in lack of object detection while running detect.py[image]